# Unable to start ios-sim on Yosemite

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode6

I have been unable to get ios-sim to start on a relatively clean isntall of Yosemite, Xcode 6 beta and Developer Tools 10.10.

```
MacOS $ ios-sim start
2014-06-10 20:34:39.578 ios-sim[4957:836370] -[__NSArrayM localizedDescription]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbc18f00380
2014-06-10 20:34:39.579 ios-sim[4957:836370] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM localizedDescription]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbc18f00380'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e4e914c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff9108257d objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e4ec07d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e435604 ___forwarding___ + 1028
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e435178 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   ios-sim                             0x0000000103e166cd -[iPhoneSimulator LoadSimulatorFramework:] + 245
    6   ios-sim                             0x0000000103e18233 -[iPhoneSimulator runWithArgc:argv:] + 2317
    7   ios-sim                             0x0000000103e185f5 main + 101
    8   ios-sim                             0x0000000103e16588 start + 52
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about support of beta software

Comment: StackOverflow does't allow questions on beta software (whatever beta even really means anymore)?

Comment: Fair enough. It apparently is because the current version of ios-sim is not compatible with Xcode6/DevTools. A fix has been posted to GitHub at robovm/ios-sim.

Comment: Old versions of ios-sim aren't compatible with the release version of Xcode 6, either. :-)

Comment: You may do it with [xcrun simctl][1] with Xcode 6 now.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031601/xcode-6-launch-simulator-from-command-line

Answer (score 8):

Updating ios-sim does the trick. https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim No need to use the fork from robovm. And now that it is no longer beta, it isn't off topic. :]

Comment: Thank you. It fixed the problem I had with last XCode and last Cordova !

Answer (score 3):

ios-sim is currently incompatible with Xcode6-beta. A fix has been posted by "robovm" at https://github.com/robovm/ios-sim