# Xcode 6 - How to Open Url in IOS Simulator Mobile Safari from Terminal?

Tags: terminal, ios-simulator, mobile-safari, xcode6

I recently updated to Xcode 6 and now [the command I was using](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117064/how-to-launch-browser-in-ios-simulator-from-command-line#answer-117066) before doesn't work:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator -SimulateApplication /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/Applications/MobileSafari.app/MobileSafari -u "http://google.com/"
```

I do a lot of front end work and responsive design and must look at the results in every browser multiple times a day. It is very painful without this command.

Also, I would like to open in IOS7 with one command and IOS8 with another.

Answer (score 22):

```
xcrun simctl openurl <Device UDID> http://www.google.com
```

You can determine the Device UDID by running `xcrun simctl list` or on newer versions, you can use "booted" instead of the UDID to refer to the currently booted device:

```
xcrun simctl openurl booted http://www.google.com
```

Note that this requires the iOS Simulator to actually be running.  Depending on the version of Xcode.app that you have, you may be able to use the "booted" alias instead of the device UDID to select the currently booted device.

You may also want to look at [Xcode 6 - Launch simulator from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031601/xcode-6-launch-simulator-from-command-line/26053018#26053018) for information about how to launch the iOS Simulator app and have it start a specific device.

Comment: Thanks bud. I don't know why but StackOverflow didn't notify me there was an answer. I'll try it today and respond. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, can you add a description of what this command is actually doing? These commands are completely foreign to me.

Comment: @stoutie Run 'xcrun simctl help' for additional help on the simctl command.  The xcrun command is a wrapper to execute simctl from within your currently selected Xcode.app.

Comment: I can't get it to work. I'm not sure from the list what the device id is? https://gist.github.com/jehoshua02/28159e9edaa53177904e#file-xcrun_simctl_list-md

Comment: You can just pass the flag: **booted** to use the current simulator so you have to look for it's UDID. Example: ```xcrun simctl openurl booted http://www.google.com```

Comment: Yep.  That was added a few months ago :)