# how to set default device in iOS simulator from command line

Tags: ios, jenkins, command-line, ios-simulator, xcode6.1

http://cl.ly/image/2K1H000s170l

Please refer to my screenshot. That's a manual way to set default device in iOS simulator. Can anyone tell me how to do that from command line? Many thanks!

I need that as part of my Jenkins project setup. Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 6 - Launch simulator from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031601/xcode-6-launch-simulator-from-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

You can use xcrun to open your device

```
xcrun instruments -w "iPhone 6 (8.4 Simulator)"
```

If you want to know all devices installed

```
xcrun instruments -s
```

If you need to build and install some app use.

```
xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator8.4 -arch i386 install DSTROOT=~/YourApp
xcrun simctl install booted ~/YourApp/Applications/YourApp.app
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the device that is booted when the simulator launches by passing it on the command line.  See [Xcode 6 - Launch simulator from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031601/xcode-6-launch-simulator-from-command-line/26053018?s=1|0.4388#26053018)

Answer (score 0):

Yes as mentioned this is a duplicate.

But to answer your question,

You can use the instruments to launch the simulator of your choice. For Ex:

```
xcrun instruments -w "iPhone 6 (8.2 Simulator)"
```

"From the screen shot it seems like you are already on iOS 8. "