# Run my app after iOS simulator is booted

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, jailbreak, launch-daemon

I want to run my app automatically in the background after the iOS Simulator is booted (probably after SpringBoard has launched).

On a jailbroken iOS device, I can accomplish this by placing a launchd.plist file inside /Library/LaunchDaemons.

Is there a way to do this on a per-device basis in the simulator?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is it even possible to jailbreak the simulator?

Comment: Simulator doesnt require jailbreak. because all the files system of simulator can be accessible by anyone. simply we can say every simulator is jailbroken by default :)

Comment: This might help, you can launch the simulator and a specific app via the command line http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031601/xcode-6-launch-simulator-from-command-line

Comment: my requirement is little different. if i follow my iOS device approach i will be able to load/unload the app anytime without rebooting the simulator. so i need an alternate approach. thanks james, got some idea from that link to move further :)

Answer (score 0):

No.  There is no way to do this on a per-device basis in the simulator.  You can place a launchd.plist in [RuntimeRoot]/Library/LaunchDaemons, but that will be used for *all* simulator devices, not just an individual one.

You can run `xcrun simctl launch booted [app id]` to launch your app manually, but it won't be in the background.