# Can't find a way to properly debug nativescript application

Tags: nativescript

I am having trouble finding a workable solution for debugging nativescript applications. I have tried the following options:

a) tns debug
This starts a tool called 'Nativescript Inspector'. It is painfully slow and to add insult to injury: it crashes more than it runs. I have not been able to it to run long enough to find even basic problems. It's perfectly useless to me.

b) tns debug --chrome
The chrome debugger is a lot better, but it seems impossible to simply reload. Every time you restart, you need to re-attach a fresh instance. Since this option works by copy & paste of a link, it becomes fairly cumbersome. Additionally, it does not really respect breakpoints properly, especially during app restarts! So ultimately, this is also useless.

c) Sidekick
This is supposed to be one of the prescribed methods of debugging. Half the time the debugger does not start. If it does, there is no way to break the flow during application start-up. Since I'm in the process of debugging parts that happen during start-up, I do never get a chance to set a breakpoint, barring tricks like wrapping the bootstrapping phase into a timer (which also costs time). So even this method is not working.

Do I really, really need to get Visual Studio? I really would like to avoid that ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To debug the Views, currently, the best option is to use the debugger that comes with Sidekick.

If you want to debug the logic, however, the best option is to use the NativeScript extension for VS Code, and debug directly from VS Code. :)
Hope this helps.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Telerik.nativescript

Comment: I was trying to avoid running another IDE. I have been using WebStorm for quite some time now and I'm very comfortable and happy with it. I was trying to avoid using VS Code.

Comment: Well then good news for you!, here's {N} plugin for WebStorm
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8588-nativescript

Comment: And article that talks about it https://medium.com/@iguissouma/the-n-plugin-for-webstormide-78525a3cfd4f

Comment: I have that installed already. I did not list it in the options above because it does not integrate the debugger. It is basically the same as option b) for debugging. Besides: the projects created with this plugin seem to be incompatible with sidekick. Attempts to run projects generated by this plugin fail invariably with code signing issues on macos.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions and infos, but ultimately of all the options present, only Visual Studio Code seems to work in any comfortable manner for the time being. I would love to see true debugging support in the WebStorm plugin, though!

Answer (score 1):

Debugging code that executes at start up is tricky, so you need to place `debugger` statements in your code, and start a debugging session with `--debug-brk`

`tns debug ios --chrome --debug-brk`

For more information, check the `Debugger` section in the Chrome DevTools docs - https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/chrome-devtools#debugger

Answer (score 1):

I´m starting with native script and I found that debugging is one of the biggest challenges.

My first approach was the native script extensión for Visual Studio Code, but it resulted a little bit unstable and Visual Studio Code lacks some features that I use a lot in webstorm.

Probably in a near future  VEC + tns extension  will be the choice, but right now my debugging strategy is:

## 1  **Launch simulator**

I'm using Osx and I want to debug in an Ipad simulator. By default the IOS simulator boots an Iphone X device. First I need to launch the simualtor with a custom device.

```
$ xcrun simctl list devices
== Devices ==
-- iOS 11.2 --
iPhone 5s (E3B6EA43-C805-49C2-9502-A44A465D8DF2) (Shutdown)
iPhone 6 (801E9E11-CA86-473A-9879-4B0742B827FB) (Shutdown)
iPhone 6 Plus (24013349-1A6F-489C-9A68-ABB00EBB4BBF) (Shutdown)
iPhone 6s (1A594D75-146C-4BEA-A250-1FADE7886114) (Shutdown)
```

Then I launch the simulator app  specifying a device with the -CurrentDeviceUDID option

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator -CurrentDeviceUDID <DEVICE-UDID>
```

NOTE: replace the  with a valid UDID from the list.

More info at [Xcode 6 - Launch simulator from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031601/xcode-6-launch-simulator-from-command-line/49517322#49517322)

## 2. **Use nativescript-cli commands**

To get a list of available devices

```
# tns devices
```

[image]

To debug in a specific device:

```
# tns debug ios --device <device identifier>
```

Note: replace the device identifier with a valid id.

If you want to debug in an emulator

```
# tns debug ios --emulator
```

You have to find the url in the command output and open in chrome:

```
...
...
To start debugging, open the following URL in Chrome:
chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/@02e6bde1bbe34e43b309d4ef774b1168d25fd024/inspector.html?experiments=true&ws=localhost:41000
....
```

More information about dedugging commands can be found in
https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/debugging

More information about debugging with chrome-dev-tools
https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/chrome-devtools#debugger

**04/20/2018 Update**

I´m developing in Mac OS X and with the new native-script cli 4.0 the debugging experience with the WebKit Web Inspector has improved. So I´m now using it for debugging:

```
tns debug ios --inspector
```